# using request.data instead of serializer class in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have been using in one of my views request.data instead of serialzer to get json data and work on it, my question is this ok or lets say "a good practice" to use request.data or should i create serializer class for that view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to use a serializer in the first place is to transform native python data types to valid JSON and vice-versa. Consequently, the serializer adds a layer of validation to make sure that this transformation process runs correctly in accordance with your serializer definition.

If you decide to omit the serializer in the views, you would have to handle data validation there yourself and you end up implementing a feature which already exists in practice and has been "battle-tested" and worked on by multiple accomplished developers. There are cases where you don't strictly need a serializer in your views, for example when you simply display data from another source and only allow GET requests, but whenever you deal with data input I would consider it bad practice to not use serializers.